# how to get iphone ipod playlist images and display it in image view

Tags: iphone, audio-player

I am working with iphone ipod to read the album and playlist and play it in my application.

My question is that that i get the image from the album i have selected. and it is also working well in my application.

But i never get images from the playlist which i have selected their are different songs in my playlist and also having different image for that songs. for the album i have get the code and it work great. i am new for this and i cant found any reference code for this.

And i am using AVPlayer to play the songs.

So please help me and provide some sample code. for how to get all images from playlist and convert that image to data in iphone.

Please help me.

Comment: if u have url of of song then u can get thumbnail of it.

Comment: sorry but i have to get the image from ipod media playlist.and i want to convert that image into data and store it on error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for is the `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` for `MPMediaItem`. As stated in the docs. After getting the artwork property you can make a `MPMediaItemArtwork` object, as stated in the docs.

> An MPMediaItemArtwork object, or media item artwork, represents a graphical image, such as music album cover art, associated with a media item. Media items are described in MPMediaItem Class Reference.

With this you can do something like this. Assuming `song` is an `MPMediaItem`:

```
UIImage *image = nil;

MPMediaItemArtwork *itemArtwork = [song valueForProperty:
                                          MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
if(itemArtwork != nil)
     image = [itemArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(100,100)];
```

Now you have `image` containing your `MPMediaItem` artwork, set it to your image view (`[myImageView setImage:image]`). Keep in mind, this will only work if artwork **IS** available.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VTM_AViPodReader](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/) demo for this.